Did Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) ever punish a Muslim woman for not wearing a jilbab, hijab, niqab, burqa, in public?
I just want to know did prophet Muhammad make strict rules if women did not wear dress well. Did they get punishment. Give me some examples please.

Short answer, i do not think so, i havent read full of the story of Muhammad SAW but I dont think that that is what he would even dare to do, CMIIW (correct me if im wromg)

Relevant Is there an legal punishment for not wearing hijab according to sharia? and Was hijab in public enforced legally in premodern times?

No. While it is fard (mandatory) for Muslim women to wear hijab and this is known in religion by necessity, there is no punishment if they don’t wear. Wearing hijab for Muslim women is fard in the same way prayer and fasting is fard. Denying the obligation of hijab and jilbab is kufr (disbelief) and takes the denier out of Islam. And Allah says in the Quran, “ And tell the believing women to lower their gaze and guard their chastity, and not to reveal their adornments except what normally appears. Let them draw their veils over their chests, and not reveal their ˹hidden˺ adornments except to their husbands, their fathers, their fathers-in-law, their sons, their stepsons, their brothers, their brothers’ sons or sisters’ sons, their fellow women, those ˹bondwomen˺ in their possession, male attendants with no desire, or children who are still unaware of women’s nakedness. Let them not stomp their feet, drawing attention to their hidden adornments. Turn to Allah in repentance all together, O  believers, so that you may be successful.” [Surah Nur verse 31]  A woman who doesn’t wear hijab but still believes in it to be mandatory and doesn’t deny it being fard is sinful but not a kafir. In the same way, for instance if a person missed Fajr prayer but they knew it was sinful and they felt bad about it this is one condition it doesn't make them a non-muslim that just makes them a bad Muslim and a major sinner unless they repent if a person misses prayer regularly or doesn’t pray at all and doesn't feel bad about it yet they nonetheless still believe that prayer is important and mandatory and don’t deny it being fard and important it doesn't make them a kafir it makes them a worse Muslim than the first one however if a Muslim believes he doesn't have to pray and that it isn’t mandatory or important or that Allah was incorrect In commanding us to do so so he doesn't pray because he doesn't feel it's necessary or mandatory that is when he becomes a kafir or even if he does pray but claims it’s only recommend or optional and not fard then he also is a kafir. Similarly, those who claim that it’s only recommended or only optional for Muslim women to wear hijab, this is kufr that takes the person out of Islam because denying religious obligations that are known in the religion by necessity by ijma’a is kufr. And she is ordered to wear jilbab. What is jilbab? - it is mandatory for Muslim women to wear loose clothing and clothing that is not see through and clothing that covers the shape of the breasts to the best of her ability and the figure of the female. The four conditions that counts as jilbab is clothing that covers the awrah, is thick and opaque (not transparent or see through), loose and modest. This can be something that is a separate loose garment worn over one’s clothes, or simply loose clothing that fulfills the above-mentioned conditions. There are many Muslim women who wear the hijab that covers their head but then they wear tight-fitted clothing such as leggings or tight-fitted jeans and this is completely haram. However, it is okay for Muslim women to wear pants as long as they’re loose, and not see through and of course has no rips that expose the awrah. The women’s awrah is the whole body except for the hands and face and in the Hanafi madhab, the women’s feet also is not awrah and therefore it is permissible for Muslim women to pray barefoot without socks or to wear flip flops or open toed sandals in public as long as the entire legs are covered. In the Maliki madhab, the base of the women’s feet is not awrah but the rest of the foot is. What is the woman ordered to cover? The woman is ordered to not show her figure to those males who are not related to her. And this relates to modesty. Muslim women of course are required to cover the hair which is known as hijab. Can we enforce this hijab? The answer is no. We as individuals cannot force hijab upon the females. Women are ordered to wear hijab by Allah (subhanahu wa ta’ala). The Quran itself orders them to wear the hijab and as believing women they are obligated to do so. But as males is there any punishment that is mentioned in the Quran or Sunnah that if a female doesn’t wear hijab she’s punished? The answer is no. This is a religious obligation upon Muslim females to do. Is the niqab (covering the face) an obligation upon Muslim women? - the answer is no. The Quran does not mention the niqab. The Quran mentions the jilbab which is covering the breasts, the figure of the women, clothing that is loose and not transparent and covering the hair. This is by agreement of the scholars. As for covering the face, many scholars actually have stated that it is ghuluw. In fact this is the position of the Maliki madhab that wearing the niqab is actually makrooh (discouraged) and ghuluw (extremism, exaggeration, excessiveness). Imam Khalil (rahimahullah) in the book of pre-conditions of Salah, the coverage of a woman and the coverage of a man in prayer and what is discouraged states how wearing the niqab for Muslim women is ghuluw. Al-Dardir says, “covering her face with niqab (whether inside the prayer or outside the prayer) and that which reaches the eye is ghuluw because it is from what is extremism, what is extremes and ghuluw in the sharia.” The definition of ghuluw is to obligate that which Allah did not obligate. The problem now in Iran now where women are taking off their scarves, the Iranian government firstly instead of enforcing hijab, they should instead instruct the women with regards to the wisdom of hijab. You cannot enforce the hijab. In the Quran and Sunnah, there is no punishment mentioned. The Quran instructs believing women (it’s fard) that they should wear hijab but there is no punishment mentioned. So the rulers must be wise in this day and age and they must advise the women with al-‘mu’idha and al-hasana and with hikmah with regards to the wisdom on why women cover and that their freedom is in covering, that they are given that respect. How many cases have happened with Epstein, Weinstein and other steens and also Jimmy Saville and all these other people and many cases in the West of sexual abuse that occurs. Why? Because if they followed Sharia, which our sharia tells us we cannot be alone in the same room with someone of the opposite gender unless she is related to you. The Messenger of Allah (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) said in an authentic Hadith that it is better to have a piece of iron put into the hand then to shake hands with someone of the opposite gender. So if men cannot even shake hands with a woman then men can never sexually abuse women because they cannot even touch her, she’s haram for them. And therefore in the laws of Islam, there is utmost respect for women
